# I have polygon data saved as a long text string of coordinates saved as .csv. How can I add it into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, json

The data provided to me are saved as .csv files, and are listed in this manner:

{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[120.9919351,14.5451086],[120.9939584,14.545671],[120.9937922,14.5461149],[120.9941719,14.5462298],[120.9952644,14.5465698],[120.9953175,14.5463393],[120.9955468,14.5454097],[120.9955627,14.5453573],[120.9961743,14.5454329],[120.9963335,14.5448206],[120.9965709,14.5438329],[120.9968565,14.5432642],[120.9969909,14.5427672],[120.9947601,14.5422615],[120.9947116,14.5424894],[120.9943456,14.5424543],[120.9931804,14.5421634],[120.9927979,14.5420574],[120.9919351,14.5451086]]]}

I am able to use this as actual polygon layers in kepler.gl, but I am not able to use these in QGIS.

Comment: That is geojson not a CSV, just drag it into QGis

Comment: Works if the file extension is set to `.geojson`, not with `.csv`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new, empty polygon layer in 'EPSG:4326'
2. Create any simple polygon - we won't need it later, you can delete it afterwards.
3. Run [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression) (see also [here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) and insert the following expression (explanation at the bottom), but on line 5, instead of `your_string`, insert your string from your question (from `{` to `}`) and keep the single quotes `'`:

   ```
    geom_from_wkt( 
        'Polygon ((' ||
        regexp_replace( 
            regexp_replace( 
            'your_string',  -- replace this
            '(\\d)(,)(\\d)','\\1 \\3'),
        '.*:|\\[|\\]|}','')
    || '))')
   ```

*The solution, here demonstrated with geometry generator:*
[image]

**Explanation:**

1. Use regular expressions with [`regexp_replace()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-replace) to replace in the input string all commas that separate digits by a space, like this `4,5` becoming `4 5`.
2. Use regular expressions with [`regexp_replace()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-replace) to replace (delete) from the changed input string (using logical OR operator `|`):

   - everything up to (and including) the (first) double point `:` (as regex: `.*:`)
   - opening bracket `[` (as regex: `\\[`, `\\` is for masking the `[`)
   - closing bracket `]` (as regex: `\\]`)
   - closing bracket `}`

   Instead of

   `{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[120.9919351 14.5451086],[120.9939584 14.545671],...,[120.9919351 14.5451086]]]}`

   you then have left only the coordinate values in an appropriate format:

   `'120.9919351 14.5451086,120.9939584 14.545671,...,120.9919351 14.5451086'`
3. Add `'Polygon ((' ||` at the beginning and `|| '))'` at the end with the pipe operator [`||`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-concat) to get

   `'Polygon (( 120.9919351 14.5451086,120.9939584 14.545671,...,120.9919351 14.5451086 ))'`

   which is the syntax you need.
4. Convert this WKT string to a polygon using [`geom_from_wkt()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#geom-from-wkt)